# Using Google analytics, Is it possible to create Custom dimension using API (programatically)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am working on a SaaS application, where I let user(s) to use their own google analytics account for tracking their site.

While tracking, I also wants to take benefit of custom dimensions. It is not possible to telling/educating each client(*most of them are non-technical*) about "*how to create custom dimension/metric using Google Analytic Interface*".

Is there any way, that I can create custom dimension using code.
something like

```
ga('<command>','<dimension name>', '<index>', '<scope>')
```

Comment: couldn't find anything to start with. All the documents refers to creating custom dimension with interface.

Comment: This is from Google. You must setup the custom dimensions in via the interface first. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: @colecmc yes you are right, but any work around, anything.. that i could create dimension using API.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Maybe check out google tag manager. See if GTM did anything sneaky to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom Dimensions in the Google Analytics Management API, see:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/insert

There is some example code for working with the api here:
https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/analytics-cmdline-sample

Good luck :)